# Cannot get value from base class constructor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have a issue with getting constructor values from my base class. I have register services in my Startup.cs like that:

```
functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IBaseClass>(_ => new BaseClass(envName, pool));
functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ISecondClass, SecondClass>();
functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IThirdClass, ThirdClass>();
```

BaseClass implementation:

```
    public class BaseClass: IBaseClass
    {
        private readonly string _envName;
        private readonly IRedisConnectionPoolManager _pool;
    
            public BaseClass(string envName, IRedisConnectionPoolManager pool)
            {
                _envName = envName;
                _pool = pool;
            }
    
            public async Task<bool> ReplaceItemAsync<TItem>(string objId, TItem value)
            {
                //replace item
            }
      }
```

And that how my Second/Third class look like (because both of them are using Base class but in a little bit other ways).

```
public class SecondClass : BaseClass, ISecondClass
{
    public SecondClass (string envName, IRedisConnectionPoolManager pool) : base(envName, pool)
    {
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> ReplacebyIdAsync(string id, T value)
    {
        var data = await ReplaceItemAsync<List<T>>(id, value);
        return data;
    }
```

When I am registering BaseClass in statrup I can see that envName and pool are not null but when SecondClass or ThirdClass call their constructor then I can see that value passed to BaseClass constructor are null. When I am registering Services like that than everything is fine (but as I understand this is not good approach).

```
    functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IBaseClass>(_ => new BaseClass(envName, pool));
    functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ISecondClass >(_=> new SecondClass(envName, pool));
    .
    .
    .
```

How can I be able to use ReplaceItemAsync method among my other class without passing envName and pool to each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I am registering BaseClass in statrup I can see that envName and pool are not null but when SecondClass or ThirdClass call their constructor then I can see that value passed to BaseClass constructor are null

Because in case of `BaseClass` you provide a value factory for service of type `IBaseClass`. You need to do the same for others too (as you done). In general DI container does not care about the inheritance relation between the service implementations.

> How can I be able to use ReplaceItemAsync method among my other class without passing envName and pool to each of them?

Register `pool` and wrapper for `envName` and allow DI to resolve it. Something along these lines:

```
public record EnvHolder(string EnvName);

// ...
public BaseClass(EnvHolder env, IRedisConnectionPoolManager pool)
// ...
public SecondClass(EnvHolder env, IRedisConnectionPoolManager pool) : base(envName, pool)
```

And register everything:

```cs
functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IRedisConnectionPoolManager>(_ => pool);
functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => new EnvHolder(envName));
functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IBaseClass, BaseClass>();
functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ISecondClass, SecondClass>();
functionBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IThirdClass, ThirdClass>();
```

Read more:

- [.NET dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)

Comment: It works thank you! But I have one more question is there other way to deal with this envName instead of doing this wrapper? I am asking because envName is a simple string and I am not sure if it should be registered.

Comment: @Maltion you can register a string but in general I would argue that it is a bad practice for multiple reasons.

Comment: Hmm maybe it would be also fine to construct envName in BaseClass constructor like that:

'        public BaseClass(IRedisConnectionPoolManager pool)
        {
            _environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("envName", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            _pool = pool;
        }'

Comment: @Maltion yes, that is an option, though personally I would not go with it and used the wrapper.